# Visual Studio 2013: C Application on any Windows version

Tags: c, windows, dll, visual-studio-2013

### The situation

I have an app created in Visual Studio 2013 written in C. It work flawlessly on my computer (Windows 7) and on other Windows 7 computers that I have tested the app on.

### The Issue

In order for my app to work, Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable has to be installed otherwise a couple of other .dll files are needed (`MSVCR120.DLL` for example). When I tried this on Windows XP I confronted with the following error:

> C:\path\to\app.exe is not a valid Win32 application

and found no way of solving that.

### The Question

How can I solve all the problems and have a single `.exe` file that works on any Windows system regardless of its configuration without the need of extra files or an installer?

#### Bonus Question

What are these `MSVCR***.dll` files?

Comment: Where are the `MSVCR***.dll` files?  You can find this out yourself by running your app with a debugger or Process Monitor.

Comment: These files are generally in `C:\Windows\System32`, but I wanted to know what is inside them, why are they needed. Now I know thanks to @edtheprogrammerguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can statically link to the vc runtime and that should eliminate the need for installing dependencies.  Note that the .exe will be larger because the dependencies are compiled in.

Set `/MT` for Release and `/MTd` for Debug in `Project Settings -> C/C++ -> Code Generation`

You can also set `v120_xp` in `General -> Platform Toolset` for your program to be able to run in Windows XP  (http://supportxpdotcom.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/xp-targeting-support-in-the-visual-studio-2013-preview/)

The MSVCR*** files are  C run-time library files that hold the functionality for C run-time functions used in a program.  When you statically link a program, you compile them in to the .exe and so don't have to distribute them separately. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272081(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the `/MT` solved one problem. I couldn't test it on Windows XP but I believe the `v120_xp` solves the other one.